# Use of spark to optimize S3 to S3 transfer

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, sdk

I am learning spark/scala and trying to experiment with the below scenario using scala language.
Scenario: Copy multiple files from one S3 bucket folder to another S3 bucket folder.

Things done so far:
1) Use AWS S3 SDK and scala:
- Create list of files from S3 source locations.
- Iterate through the list, pass the source and target S3 locations from step 1 and use S3 API `copyObject` to copy each of these files to the target locations (configured).
This works.

However, I am trying to understand if I have large number of files inside multiple folders, is this the most efficient way of doing or can I use spark to parallelize this copy of files?

The approach that I am thinking is:
1) Use S3 SDK to get the source paths similar to what's explained above 
2) Create an RDD for each of the files using sc.parallelize() - something on these lines?
`sc.parallelize(objs.getObjectSummaries.map(_.getKey).toList)
        .flatMap { key => Source.fromInputStream(s3.getObject(bucket, key).getObjectContent: InputStream).getLines }`

3) Can I use sc.wholeTextFiles in some way to make this work?
I am not sure how to achieve this as of now.

Can you please help me understand if I am thinking in the right direction and also is this approach correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think AWS did not make it complicated though.

We had the same problem, we transferred around 2TB close to 10 mins.

If you want to transfer from one bucket to another bucket, better to use the built-in functionality to transfer within s3 itself.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

**AWS CLI Command Example:**

> aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket s3://destinationbucket

If you want to do it programmatically you can use all SDK's to invoke the same type of command. I would avoid reinventing the same wheel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. However, I was trying to figure out if there are large number of files, can spark be used for making this process faster?

Comment: If you have partitioned data, you can increase your throughput by running those commands parallelly through those partitions. If your objects are not partitioned, then it does not make any sense.

Comment: Was just revisiting this question. 2 TB in 10 minutes how? using sync CLI? I am getting max 200 MBps from AWS infrastructure itself. Is it 2 TB or 2 GB?

Comment: Double check on your networking throughput to ec2. Also keep the region same. Tested on c5n.18xlarge.

Comment: ok, that will make a difference c5n. I was using t2 micro. Thanks that explains.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code snipped, [cloudCp](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala) which uses spark for a high-performance parallelised upload; it'd be similar to do something for copy, where you'd drop to the AWS lib for that operation.

But: you may not need to push out work to many machines, as each of the PUT/x-copy-source calls may be slow, but it doesn't use any bandwidth. You could just start a process with many many threads & a large HTTP client pool and just run them all on in that process. Take the list, sort by largest few first and then shuffle the rest at random to reduce throttling effects. Print out counters to help profile...

Comment: Thanks. I will try and get back

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code to sync many folders recursively in parallel. List all upper level objects inside some folder or bucket, prepare a dataset with list of commands and foreach execute a command. See comments in the code.

Executed on 50 executors, (4 cores, 6g) each, 1Tb in 1minute.
The reason why I did not parallelize copying every object in separate command is that I have many folders with too many files in each and I do not need too much parallelizm to keep my cluster alive for other tasks, so I used aws s3 sync for syncing folders recursively instead of each file.
If you need just copy all the files, not sync, then use `aws s3 cp`, it works faster than `sync`. Use `sync` if some data is already copied and you need to copy missing objects only.

```
import collection.JavaConversions._ 
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Result
import sys.process._

val srcBucket = "source_bucket_name"
val tgtBucket = "target_bucket_name"
val prefix = "folder/" //set to empty if you need to copy all bucket content


def listObjects(str: String): List[String] = {
        val s3_client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build()
        val request: ListObjectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(srcBucket).withDelimiter("/").withPrefix(str)
        val result = s3_client.listObjectsV2(request)
        val directories = result.getCommonPrefixes()
        directories.toList
      }

//Function to be used in map() to construct cp or sync command for each DF element 
def getCpString(key: String, srcBucket: String, tgtBucket: String): String = {
    s"aws s3 sync s3://$srcBucket/$key s3://$tgtBucket/$key --size-only"
}

val directories = listObjects(prefix)

val ds=directories.toDS.repartition(50).map(row => getCpString(row, srcBucket, tgtBucket))

//filter ds if necessary like this .filter(not($"value".contains("some_folder/")))
//check command list
ds.show(500, false)


//Now execute commands in parallel
ds.rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
    partition.foreach(command=>{
                           //read stderr and stdout 
                           //to make sure 
                           //the command will be not locked
                           //when stdout/stderr buffer is full
                           val status = s"$command" ! ProcessLogger((o: String) => println(command + " out " + o),(e: String) => println(command + " error " + e))
           })
})
```